# Connect multiple (two) windows phones to the computer at the same time and develop

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm developing an app on windows phone that simply can't work without at least two phones (Two phones need to see each other through wireless network and act together. And I use an API that is not properly implemented on emulator).

Unplug the first one and plug in another repeatedly as I'm modifying the code and watching changes on the phones is painful.

Is it possible that I connect two windows phones, and make them work, at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to connect multiple phones to the same PC at once. The connection used by Zune (or WPConnect) only works with one device at a time.

I've been in a similar situation to you (debugging software on multiple phones at the same time--as they talk to each other) but there's no way round this.

Comment: Yes, I've tried both. While Zune displays one connected device at a time, WPConnect explicitly tells me that I shouldn't plug 2 phones at the same time. It's so sad. Thank you!